Install Python packages with Chef
What is the best practice for installing Python pip packages with Chef?
I thought about the poise-python, but I've read that it stops maintenance.
And a direct install at recipe like:
execute 'python modules' do 
    command 'pip install toposort==1.5.0'         
    ignore_failure true            
end

It makes something cause which not install and drop the recipe, that is the reason of adding the ignore_failure true.
